# Displaying only last array in list

Tags: jquery

I have this problem whit array output. Only **last** array is displayed in the list. But I want to display **all** of these arrays whit jQuery.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul").append("<li></li>").text(filmi.Movies[0].Title) //La La Land
        $("ul").append("<li></li>").text(filmi.Movies[1].Title) //Fracture
        $("ul").append("<li></li>").text(filmi.Movies[2].Title) //Legend
        $("ul").append("<li></li>").text(filmi.Movies[3].Title) //Locke
        $("ul").append("<li></li>").text(filmi.Movies[4].Title) //Mad Max: Fury Road
});
```

**Fiddle JS:** https://jsfiddle.net/jjhn1j5t/2/

> Displayed is only: *Mad Max: Fury Road*

But it should look like this:

```
-La La Land
-Fracture
-Legend
-Locke
-Mad Max: Fury Road
```

Comment: Every time you use `.text()` you're overwriting what was previously  there. You need to append to what was there.

Comment: Find [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjhn1j5t/3/)

Comment: Make sure you end every line with a `;` or you may get unexpected results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do something like

```
$("ul").append("<li>"+filmi.Movies[0].Title+"</li>")
```

Comment: The brackets are unnecessary here. `$("ul").append("<li>"+filmi.Movies[0].Title+"</li>")`

Answer (score 5):

The way it is written, `.text()` overwrites what is inside of `$('ul')`, rather than what is inside the `li` element. You could change each line to use this format instead:

```
$("ul").append($("<li></li>").text(filmi.Movies[0].Title))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.text()` call is overwritting the `$("ul")` not the `<li>` your appending as you expect. `$("ul").append("<li></li>")` does not return the `<li>` your still working on the `<ul>`

I'd do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
       addFilm(filmi.Movies[i].Title);
    }
});

function addFilm(value){
    var $li = $("<li/>");
    $li.text(value);
    $("ul").append($li);
}
```

Comment: Better yet, put the call to `addFilm` in a loop based on `filmi.Movies.length`

Answer (score 1):

You're simply appending to the `ul` which overwrites the `li` you just added each time. Instead, add the `li` and select the last instance of it, and then set the text of that `li`.

```
$("ul").append("<li></li>").find('li').last().text(filmi.Movies[i].Title);
```

Example jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jjhn1j5t/4/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var List = $('ul')
 var li = $('<li/>')
       .text(filmi.Movies[1].Title)
        .appendTo(List);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul").append("<li>" +filmi.Movies[0].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[1].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[2].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[3].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[4].Title + "</li>")
});

const filmi = {
  "Movies": [
    {
      "Title": "La La Land",
      "Year": "2016",
      "Rated": "PG-13",
      "Released": "25 Dec 2016",
      "Runtime": "128 min",
      "Genre": "Comedy, Drama, Music",
      "Director": "Damien Chazelle",
      "Writer": "Damien Chazelle",
      "Actors": "Ryan Gosling, Emma Stone, Amiée Conn, Terry Walters",
      "Plot": "A jazz pianist falls for an aspiring actress in Los Angeles.",
      "Language": "English",
      "Country": "USA, Hong Kong",
      "Awards": "Won 6 Oscars. Another 184 wins & 224 nominations.",
      "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzUzNDM2NzM2MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTM3NTg4OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "Ratings": [
        {
          "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
          "Value": "8.3/10"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
          "Value": "93%"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Metacritic",
          "Value": "93/100"
        }
      ],
      "Metascore": "93",
      "imdbRating": "8.3",
      "imdbVotes": "232,825",
      "imdbID": "tt3783958",
      "Type": "movie",
      "DVD": "25 Apr 2017",
      "BoxOffice": "$150,459,658.00",
      "Production": "Liongate Films",
      "Website": "http://www.lalaland.movie/",
      "Response": "True"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Fracture",
      "Year": "2007",
      "Rated": "R",
      "Released": "20 Apr 2007",
      "Runtime": "113 min",
      "Genre": "Crime, Drama, Mystery",
      "Director": "Gregory Hoblit",
      "Writer": "Daniel Pyne (screenplay), Glenn Gers (screenplay), Daniel Pyne (story)",
      "Actors": "Anthony Hopkins, Ryan Gosling, David Strathairn, Rosamund Pike",
      "Plot": "An attorney, intent on climbing the career ladder toward success, finds an unlikely opponent in a manipulative criminal he is trying to prosecute.",
      "Language": "English",
      "Country": "USA, Germany",
      "Awards": "2 wins & 2 nominations.",
      "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzIzNjQyMzkwM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg5ODQ0MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "Ratings": [
        {
          "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
          "Value": "7.2/10"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
          "Value": "71%"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Metacritic",
          "Value": "68/100"
        }
      ],
      "Metascore": "68",
      "imdbRating": "7.2",
      "imdbVotes": "146,665",
      "imdbID": "tt0488120",
      "Type": "movie",
      "DVD": "14 Aug 2007",
      "BoxOffice": "$39,000,000.00",
      "Production": "New Line",
      "Website": "http://www.fracturemovie.com/",
      "Response": "True"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Legend",
      "Year": "2015",
      "Rated": "R",
      "Released": "20 Nov 2015",
      "Runtime": "132 min",
      "Genre": "Biography, Crime, Drama",
      "Director": "Brian Helgeland",
      "Writer": "Brian Helgeland, John Pearson (book)",
      "Actors": "Paul Anderson, Tom Hardy, Christopher Eccleston, Joshua Hill",
      "Plot": "Identical twin gangsters Ronald and Reginald Kray terrorize London during the 1960s.",
      "Language": "English",
      "Country": "UK, France, USA",
      "Awards": "6 wins & 10 nominations.",
      "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDQ4MGY0NWUtY2MxOC00YzI5LTg0OTEtZjNmY2Q2ZmM0MTA1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTQzOTc3MTI@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "Ratings": [
        {
          "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
          "Value": "7.0/10"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
          "Value": "61%"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Metacritic",
          "Value": "55/100"
        }
      ],
      "Metascore": "55",
      "imdbRating": "7.0",
      "imdbVotes": "106,814",
      "imdbID": "tt3569230",
      "Type": "movie",
      "DVD": "01 Mar 2016",
      "BoxOffice": "$14,146,549.00",
      "Production": "Universal Studios",
      "Website": "http://www.legend-the-movie.com/",
      "Response": "True"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Locke",
      "Year": "2013",
      "Rated": "R",
      "Released": "18 Apr 2014",
      "Runtime": "85 min",
      "Genre": "Drama",
      "Director": "Steven Knight",
      "Writer": "Steven Knight",
      "Actors": "Tom Hardy, Olivia Colman, Ruth Wilson, Andrew Scott",
      "Plot": "Ivan Locke, a dedicated family man and successful construction manager, receives a phone call on the eve of the biggest challenge of his career that sets in motion a series of events that threaten his carefully cultivated existence.",
      "Language": "English",
      "Country": "UK, USA",
      "Awards": "7 wins & 31 nominations.",
      "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1MjE5MzU2M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzE4OTMzMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "Ratings": [
        {
          "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
          "Value": "7.1/10"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
          "Value": "91%"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Metacritic",
          "Value": "81/100"
        }
      ],
      "Metascore": "81",
      "imdbRating": "7.1",
      "imdbVotes": "100,104",
      "imdbID": "tt2692904",
      "Type": "movie",
      "DVD": "12 Aug 2014",
      "BoxOffice": "$1,326,469.00",
      "Production": "A24 Films",
      "Website": "http://www.lockethemovie.com/",
      "Response": "True"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Mad Max: Fury Road",
      "Year": "2015",
      "Rated": "R",
      "Released": "15 May 2015",
      "Runtime": "120 min",
      "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
      "Director": "George Miller",
      "Writer": "George Miller, Brendan McCarthy, Nick Lathouris",
      "Actors": "Tom Hardy, Charlize Theron, Nicholas Hoult, Hugh Keays-Byrne",
      "Plot": "A woman rebels against a tyrannical ruler in postapocalyptic Australia in search for her home-land with the help of a group of female prisoners, a psychotic worshipper, and a drifter named Max.",
      "Language": "English, Russian",
      "Country": "Australia, USA",
      "Awards": "Won 6 Oscars. Another 210 wins & 193 nominations.",
      "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUyMTE0ODcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODE4NDQzNTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "Ratings": [
        {
          "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
          "Value": "8.1/10"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
          "Value": "97%"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Metacritic",
          "Value": "90/100"
        }
      ],
      "Metascore": "90",
      "imdbRating": "8.1",
      "imdbVotes": "624,273",
      "imdbID": "tt1392190",
      "Type": "movie",
      "DVD": "01 Sep 2015",
      "BoxOffice": "$129,483,877.00",
      "Production": "Warner Bros.",
      "Website": "http://www.madmaxmovie.com/",
      "Response": "True"
    },
    {
      "Title": "The Wolf of Wall Street",
      "Year": "2013",
      "Rated": "R",
      "Released": "25 Dec 2013",
      "Runtime": "180 min",
      "Genre": "Biography, Comedy, Crime",
      "Director": "Martin Scorsese",
      "Writer": "Terence Winter (screenplay), Jordan Belfort (book)",
      "Actors": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Jonah Hill, Margot Robbie, Matthew McConaughey",
      "Plot": "Based on the true story of Jordan Belfort, from his rise to a wealthy stock-broker living the high life to his fall involving crime, corruption and the federal government.",
      "Language": "English, French",
      "Country": "USA",
      "Awards": "Nominated for 5 Oscars. Another 36 wins & 160 nominations.",
      "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxMjgxNTk0MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIyOTg2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "Ratings": [
        {
          "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
          "Value": "8.2/10"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
          "Value": "77%"
        },
        {
          "Source": "Metacritic",
          "Value": "75/100"
        }
      ],
      "Metascore": "75",
      "imdbRating": "8.2",
      "imdbVotes": "849,538",
      "imdbID": "tt0993846",
      "Type": "movie",
      "DVD": "25 Mar 2014",
      "BoxOffice": "$91,330,760.00",
      "Production": "Paramount Studios",
      "Website": "http://www.thewolfofwallstreet.com/",
      "Response": "True"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="seznam-filmov.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Movie list</h1>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col">
        <ul class="list-group"></ul>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block">Reset</button>
        <br/>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="" />
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text"></p>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
          <div class="card-block">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Web-Page</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">IMDb</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please refer to the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ritwika/02zdL2jd/

```
$("ul").append("<li>" +filmi.Movies[0].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[1].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[2].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[3].Title + "</li><li>" + filmi.Movies[4].Title + "</li>")
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
filmi.Movies.forEach((movie) =>{
   $("ul").append(`<li>${movie.Title}</li>`) 
})
```

Here is the fiddle to prove it:
https://jsfiddle.net/jjhn1j5t/5/

Comment: Bear in mind that this is ECMA6. Support in browsers is patchy at best, without a pre-compiler

Comment: I know, and nowadays it's been used everywhere!